# Is there a more efficient way to regex match/replace dates in an HTML table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I've been tasked with unifying date formats of an HTML table that has different databases feeding into it.  Utilizing a SQL procedure is not an option.  The known truths are the cells in the TBODY will be plain text or plain text wrapped in one link.

I wrote a jQuery plugin that does the job, but I'm wondering if would make sense to do innerHTML versus looping through each TD.

original plugin:

```
$.fn.reformatAllDates = function () {
  var $txt = $(this).text();

  var reformatDate = function ($str) {
    var $parts = $str.split('/'),
        $year = $parts[2],
        $month = $parts[0],
        $day = $parts[1];
    if ($parts.length === 3) {
      $month = $month.length < 2 ? '0' + $month : $month;
      $day = $day.length < 2 ? '0' + $day : $day;

      //Returns dates in sort friendly format [YYYY-MM-DD]
      return $year + '-' + $month + '-' + $day;
    }
    return $str;
  };

  var $result, $reg = new RegExp(/^\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}$/);

  while (($result = $reg.exec($txt)) !== null) {
    var $match = $reg.exec($txt)[0];
    var $newFormat = reformatDate($match);
    $txt = $txt.replace($match, $newFormat);
  }
  return $(this).html($txt);
}
```

original implementation:

```
$('table.display tbody tr td').each(function () {
  if ($(this).html().indexOf('href') >= 0)
    $(this).find('a:first').reformatAllDates();
  else
    $(this).reformatAllDates();
});
```

innerHTML implementation:

```
$('table.display tbody').reformatAllDates();
```

This works, though I haven't yet tested how big the innerHTML can be before it fails and prepared the fallback steps in...

```
$.fn.reformatAllDates = function () {
  var $result, 
      $reg = new RegExp(/\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}/),
      $r2 = new RegExp(/[\n\r\f]/g),
      $html = $(this).html();
  $html = $html.replace($r2,'');
  $html = $html.replace($r2,'');

  var reformatDate = function ($str) {
    var $parts = $str.split('/'),
        $year = $parts[2],
        $month = $parts[0],
        $day = $parts[1];
    if ($parts.length === 3) {
      $month = $month.length < 2 ? '0' + $month : $month;
      $day = $day.length < 2 ? '0' + $day : $day;
      return $year + '-' + $month + '-' + $day;
    }
    return $str;
  };

  var $match, $newFormat, $msg;
  while (($result = $reg.exec($html)) !== null) {
    $match = $reg.exec($html)[0];
    $newFormat = reformatDate($match);
    var $re = new RegExp($match,"g");
    $html = $html.replace($re, $newFormat);
  }
  return $(this).html($html);
}
```

Comment: you can move the `td` selection and loop into the plugin without changing your method of accessing the data, giving you the "ideal implementation"

Comment: @Mathletics, i was actually trying to avoid the looping, for instance I already use this on non tables, like Data Definition Lists as well.

My logic is thinking if 1000 dates, but only 25 unique dates, doing a regex on the innterHTML would make a lot more sense.

but when I try: this, myregex doesn't match at all

Comment: added failed implentation, fails as in never returns a match and just returns innerHTML that has less line breaks in it.

Comment: Have you considered keying off of a class name like `date-match` to find and replace only the fields which have a date for you to manipulate, or look for/match datanodes of certain tag type? Also, I believe you'd be better off using `$.html()` than `.innerHTML`, or `$.text()` if you can.

Comment: @Jared you're right switched back to .html() and shaved off two lines, i was struggling with removing line breaks from what html was returning but executing the replace twice fixes it oddly enough.

again my original plugin worked, just trying to shave the number of loops, seems like if a huge table. with a lot of shared wrongly formatted dates, would like to update in less swoops.

is there way to a regex on a collection of textnodes? if so that would be the way to go for sure, i am searching for the most effecient way, given my restrictions to handling on the front end.

Comment: okay I know what I need to do.. i need to have another function that turns $match into a global search.

Comment: I think you might be putting the `reformatAllDates()` on the wrong element. See: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/gkeL6/

Comment: Also, you might have a slight efficiency advantage if you put the `reg = new RegExp()` line into a closure around those two `$.fn` additions, since you really don't need to make one every time that function is called, you just need on instance of it. EDIT: Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/gkeL6/1/

Comment: Something that might be a little easier to play around with: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/gkeL6/2/

Comment: @Jared thanks, really appreciate the fiddles, my question is which is most efficient, I was already using an each, but i was thinking if i have a table of 500 rows by 10 columns that's 5000 cells i am running a match on, and then a replace or multiple replaces, and often running a replace for exact dates multiple times... where as the second version significantly trims matches run, (not cycling through a bunch of cells in a currency type column for instance) as well as the replaces are now global...

Comment: I wonder is there any performance benefit for passing the node types as an argument, versus the selector $('#dynlist dt, #dynlist dd').reformatAllDates() vs $('#dynlist').reformatAllDates('dt, dd')?

question was really if I SHOULD definitely not use the innerHTML way that appears to me to be more efficient, even if i have to check against the length of the string, for instance may have to break it up if over a certain amount.

Comment: First comment, dealing with `.innerHTML`: Strictly speaking, in a fair and perfect world, you would use `innerHTML`. Why? jQuery `$.html()` uses `.innerHTML`, so it should be good, right? In this case, no, because IE, which established `.innerHTML` years ago outside of the standards at the time, doesn't support it in the same way, especially when it comes to tables. What jQuery does is smooth over those differences between browsers. So, if you *need* the HTML content, use `$.html()` unless you're absolutely sure `.innerHTML` always gives you what you need.

Comment: On the date match, I have a question: Are you literally only looking for cell or element content in the format of `9/10/12`? If this is what you are after, then you would be better off not even using a RegEx, since there is a lot of overhead associated with this. You could literally just go to the split after getting the `$.text()`, which will always be faster than `$.html()`.

Comment: And... To the question about `'#dynlist dt, #dynlist dd'` vs passing the subselect in, the first can only be slower, and will only be the same speed if jQuery is smart enough to understand that `#dynlist` is in there twice. Literally, there is no reason to do it this way. The reason I split the functions the way I did was so that the logic of both would make sense; the way you have it as one function is literally illogical to run *on the elements you want to affect*. Using a `$.find()` on a previous jQuery result is a known efficiency gain, and caching is also a major performance boost.

Comment: Here a fiddle with options of adding rows and columns for a table, as well as profiling: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/gkeL6/7/

Comment: Here's probably how I might approach it: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/gkeL6/8/ You'll see I allow the text and parts to be passed in, in case those values can be provided (and so they're not twice computed for example). Also, you'll see I use `text.match(/\/g)` in the `$.reformatAllDates()` function before calling the `$.reformatDate()`, which narrows the list and is less expensive than the whole check using the regex object. In Firefox, I get consistent 1.5 second times to reformat 10000 cells, and .15 seconds to check 10000 cells already formatted.

Comment: The times in Chrome are even better: 1.15 seconds to format 10000 cells, and .03 to .09 seconds to iterate over a formatted table. If I add another 10000 cells, now 20000 cells with 10000 unformatted, it takes 1.19 seconds to format the new cells, and about .07 seconds to iterate over 20000 formatted cells.

Comment: Of course, IE(9) has to be a dog in the times: ~30 seconds to reformat 10000 rows, although only .18 seconds to iterate over the same formatted cells. This leads me to believe the RegEx object is to blame, although it could also be the `$.text()` write to the cell.

Comment: Note, in IE9, `this.innerHTML = formatted date` literally doesn't work, but it takes just a fraction of a second to run. So I tried `$.html()` instead of `$.text()`, and it only took 8.3 seconds to run the reformat on cells needing format. So it appears `$this.html(formatted date)` provides a significant performance improvement in IE(9), while `.innerHTML` literally doesn't work.

Comment: And the times seem better for all browsers using `$.html()` instead of `$.text()` to set the reformatted date: .9 seconds to reformat in FF, 0.43 in Chrome. Looks like `$this.html(formatted date)` is the winner at this point. The fiddle in question: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/gkeL6/10/

Comment: how do i mark this as answered? @Jared thanks for the fiddles, yours didn't account for links in the TD, but I can go from there, it's always nice to see different approaches, and I like how you benchmarked/profiled your code with timestamps =)
I really don't like doing this on the frontend and thinking of tackling this at an XSLT level, but it was a fun exercise nonetheless.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with XLST, but it seems like it could potentially make the transformation more efficiently. You might also add that as another answer to this question; I'm sure others would probably like to see how do that, as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is what I came up with. To understand how I came to the following, read through the comments under the question.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var reg = new RegExp(/^\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}$/);

    $.fn.reformatAllDates = function (subselect) {
        var $this = $(this),
            $nodes,
            $node,
            text,
            matched;

        if (subselect) {
            $nodes = $this.find(subselect);
        } else if ($this.is('table')) {
            $nodes = $this.find('td');
        } else if ($this.is('dl')) {
            $nodes = $this.find('dt, dd');
        } else {
            $nodes = $this.children();
        }

        for (var i = 0, l = $nodes.size(); i < l; i++) {
            $node = $($nodes[i]);
            text = $node.text();
            matched = text.match(/\//g);

            if (matched !== null && matched.length == 2) {
                $node.reformatDate(text);
            }
        }
    };

    $.fn.reformatDate = function(text, parts) {
        var $this = $(this),
            matched,
            year,
            month,
            day;

        if (!parts) {
            text = text ? text : $this.text();
            matched = reg.exec(text);
            parts = matched !== null ? matched[0].split('/') : [];
        }

        if (parts.length === 3) {
            month = parts[0];
            day = parts[1];
            year = parts[2];

            month = month.length < 2 ? '0' + month : month;
            day = day.length < 2 ? '0' + day : day;

            //Returns dates in sort friendly format [YYYY-MM-DD]
            $this.html(year + '-' + month + '-' + day);
        }
    };

    $('#trigger').click(function(){
        $('#tabledata').reformatAllDates();
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/gkeL6/10/